# Convert Desktop application into server app

Tags: c#, c++, web-services, web-applications, pinvoke

I have Desktop application which I need to move to server so that multiple instance of that application can run.

For Desktop application I have used C++ for core application logic and C# to integrate it with front end. The architecture of the Desktop application is as follows:

1.To communicate between C# and C++ I have used P/Invoke.
2.C++ also needs to send some message back to C# at different point of time. For that 
  a. C# gives function callback to C++.
  b. C++ stores it in global variable

```
 typedef void (__stdcall *Callback) (BSTR str);
 Callback Handler;

 extern "C" 
 {
   void __declspec(dllexport) __stdcall SetCallback(Callback handler);
 }
```

1. There are multiple functions which C# call and all of them are global variable.
2. Inside application I start another thread  which opens socket to communicate with some server.

What is the best approach to convert this application into server side application? 
Can I continue using P/Invoke?
If I have to change global variable into class variable, how I create a class which can use P/Invoke?
Or I create an instance of the C++ code in C#? (How?)

Please guide me on this one.

Thanks

Comment: Your question is very unclear - unless you have very special logic any application can run multiple instances under same/multiple users. Please clarify what problem you have with current app so it can't run in new environment.

Comment: Please when you vote up explain what OP wants to do...

Comment: I think in my code Global variable and function can cause the issue?
The biggest question I have is how to create C++ class in C# with P/Invoke function call?
Preserve Callback function in C++ so that it will be usable in full lifetime of the instance?

Comment: The idea of global variables in C++, C# P/Invoking, and a desire to effectively turn it in to client/server is raising the hairs on my back.  Why did you choose to use one language for one part, and another, for the other?  Changing a fundamentally "client only" app to a "client/server" app is a difficult job - unless I am missing something you have a long, hard, road ahead.  And not the good kind of "long and hard".

Comment: @user2132017 - sorry, please read your question - it says "so that multiple instance of that application can run", there is no mentioning of client-server redesign (except maybe in tags, but often people put them at random). If you indeed want to turn it into some sort of service and Moo-Juice pretty much summed all up.